# Binding Date to DatePicker is not working in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, datepicker, uwp

I have a DateTime datatype variable,which is binded to a datepicker. 
DatePicker XAML:

```
<CalendarDatePicker Name="dpDate" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
         Date="{Binding dpDateTime, ElementName=this, Mode=TwoWay}"
         DateChanged="dp_DateChanged">
</CalendarDatePicker>
```

Code behind, which sets the value:

```
dpDatetime = DateTime.Now;
```

But datepicker is not selecting the current date it is selecting the date as 1/1/1917

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the date you are setting is of type `DateTime` while the calendar expects a `DateTimeOffset`.

You can fix this quite easily by changing the type of your `dpDateTime` property to `DateTimeOffset`.

Overall it is better to use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` everywhere because it includes timezone information which makes your code more reliable when the user's timezone changes.

### Update - `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Also you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that the value changes are notified to the data-binding. First you have to add implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your class:

```
public class Page : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

And you then update the property setter to utilize the setter:

```
private DateTimeOffset _dpDateTime = DateTime.Now;

public DateTimeOffset dpDateTime
{
   get { return _dpDateTime; }
   set 
   {  
       _dpDateTime = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Data binding functionality requires the target properties raise the `PropertyChanged` event, because data-binding behind the scenes observes this event.

Comment: I have changed it to `DateTimeOffset` but it's not working.

Comment: Please add the updated code of `dpDateTime` code to the question, so I can see what you are using

Comment: In my model I've given `dpDateTime` as
`public DateTimeOffset dpDateTime {get; set;}`  then I've given
`dpDateTime=DateTime.Now.ToUTC();`
 Model is updating with the correct value but the calendar is taking only current time and date it is taking as 1/1/1918.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the implementation you need :-)